# Visions of Hell Realm in Contemplation- What does it mean

Tags: hells

Yesterday while reading a book suddenly my mind generated the following visions: I saw a girl in a white dress being tortured in this very unpleasant place which smelled bad and was horrible , I saw her being raped by this creature who looked horrific , again and again these visions came to me in the night.

What could these visions mean ? Are they trying to warn me of some bad karma ripening. As it is said by many Tibetan teachers that they get warnings of future happenings in dreams. Although this was not a dream.

Comment: I don't think that "what does my dream mean?" is an answerable question on this site. Maybe (I don't know) your teacher would know how to answer it.

Comment: Did the girl look similar to you?

Comment: No , but I identified a lot with her

Answer (score 3):

Some relevant advice here (from *[Awareness Itself -- Visions & Signs](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/fuang/itself.html#vision)*) by Ajaan Fuang:

> § "Don't have anything to do with the past or the future. Just stay
>   with the present — that's enough. And even though that's where you're
>   supposed to stay, you're not supposed to latch onto it. So why do
>   think you should latch on to things where you're not even supposed to
>   stay?"
>
> § "You know that you shouldn't believe even your own visions, so why
>   go believing the visions of others?"
>
> § **"If you can't let go of your visions, you'll never gain release."**
>
> § One of Ajaan Fuang's students asked him, "When you see something in
>   a vision, how can you know whether it's true or false?"
>
> His answer: "Even when it's true, it's true only in terms of
>   convention. You have to get your mind beyond both true and false."
>
> § "The purpose of the practice is to make the heart pure. All these
>   other things are just games and entertainment."

Answer (score 1):

first I apologize, this question, and my answer are not about Buddhism, purely about your vision.

It is actually a very positive vision in this context, please do not be frightened by it.

The girl represents the innocent, but in the sense of the *unenlightened*. She is the maiden who holds firmly her chastity (as the novice holds to his grasping mind). This monster which forces her, is the coming of great knowledge in your practice. You will find what you have searched for. It will arrive like a stampeding herd. You will leave behind things that you once valued, but now no longer need. In their place, you will find an improved practice.

breathe... practice, and allow.